# How do I make auto-tiles react to other tiles in Godot?

Tags: bitmap, 2d-games, godot

I am creating a tileset for a 2D platformer in Godot v3.1, however, I seem to have run into something I'm not sure how to fix. I followed [this github post](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/17063) on creating one and I managed to copy the bitmask exactly for my platformer tileset.

The issue: **SLOPES!**

Auto-tile working properly: [Image](https://i.ibb.co/Jj4yRp9/Screen-Shot-2019-06-02-at-4-10-02-PM.png)

Auto-tile not reacting to a different tile: [Image](https://i.ibb.co/MNbMFrQ/Screen-Shot-2019-06-02-at-4-10-09-PM.png)

How would I get the auto-tile to react with other tiles (i.e. connect to the slope in this scenario)? Or at least control how the auto-tile works in specific scenarios. I assume adding it to the bitmask somehow would probably not work as then I couldn't control when a slope would appear or a one-high wall. Any ideas or workarounds?
 
**Note:**
The platform is an auto-tile and the slope is part of an atlas.

Answer (score 0):

Auto tiles can only detect other auto-tiles of the same set.

You can add your slope to the autotile sprite, and configure the bitmask properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no inspector option to make autotiles consider other tilesets, but there is a callback function for it.  Read the "Autotile binding" secion of this Godot doc, and see what it says about "_is_tile_bound(drawn_id, neighbor_id)":

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/2d/using_tilemaps.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).